# X value for given y value

Tags: matlab, signals, axis

i have a very simple question but i can't find my wrong. I have two signals, one same x axes and two signals value on y axis. I need to find the y value of green signal on the black line, so where y value of blue signal is 50.05. It should be between 6-7. I thought that i should first get same x value (4.676). Then get the y value of green signal where x is 4.676. So i need to get first 4.676 but i can't get this x value on given y value. I tried this but it comes always empty matrix.

`xvalue = interp1(x_bluesignal,y_bluesignal, 50.05)`

and

```
idx = find(x_bluesignal == 50.05);
Xidx = x_bluesignal(idx);
```

Any idea? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: `find` will not return the index because equality cannot be determined for floating point numbers. Try using find with a threshold or use [ismembertol](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html)

Comment: you should interpolate on the x value not the y one. So `green_val = interp1(x_blue,y_green,4.676)`

Comment: In addition to what @UnbearableLightness said, you can also use `idx = find(abs(x_blue-50.05)<tol)` where `tol` is your tolerance, for example 0.01

Comment: @obchardon thank you for your help. It works very well. And just one question please. I can get just y value of blue, and i need to first get x value 4.676. Do you know, how can i get the blue x value (6.767) when the y value is 50.05?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @obchardon pointed out in the comments, you want to interpolate on the x-value, not the y-value. As a simple example, consider the following:

```
%Plot two original lines
x = linspace(0,20,101);
y1 = 5*x+2;
y2 = 3*x+5;
plot(x, y1, 'b', x, y2 ,'g'); hold on

%Plot intersection line at desired y_interest value
y_interest = 50.05;
xvalue = interp1(y1, x, y_interest);
plot([xvalue, xvalue], [0, 100], 'k--')

x_interest = interp1(x, y2, xvalue);
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

Once you've interpolated on x to find the correct x-value, you can then feed that value to your next interpolation on the y-values of the green curve. In the example above, this will output `33.8300`.

Comment: thank you but i get this error  `Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing.

Error in interp1 (line 183)
        F = griddedInterpolant(X,V,method);

Error in probe (line 29)
xvalue = interp1(STWA_ref, Zeit_ref,y_interest);
 `

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing what `STWA_ref` and `Zeit_ref` are. I would look at those vectors and determine that the vector you are interpolating w.r.t. is monotonically increasing as it states.

Answer (score -2):

In both your attempts you are actually asking MATLAB for the `y` value where `x` is 50.05, rather than your intended query.
Both

`xvalue = interp1(y_bluesignal,x_bluesignal, 50.05)`

and

`idx = find(y_bluesignal == 50.05);
Xidx = x_bluesignal(idx);`

may work if there is an entered data point at `y=50.05` (use a tolerance as in the above comments if this is a calculated value), the interp method will work regardless

Comment: I've downvoted your answer, because your `xvalue` is useless, we already know that xvalue will be close to `4.676`. Aure U is looking for the corresponding green_value. And as mentionned by UnberableLightness comparing two floating point numbers won't give you an equality, try to run `0.3 - 0.1 == 0.2`

Comment: Read the question again, finding xvalue using code IS what they are having trouble doing

Comment: @etmuse, OP is asking "I need to find the y value of green signal"

Comment: @Zep "So i need to get first 4.676 but i can't get this x value on given y value." Yes they overall want the green y value but the initial problem was how to get xvalue